# Let $G$ be a group in which $aba = b \; \forall a,b \in G$. Prove that $G$ is Abelian.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, abelian-groups

I was wondering if someone could tell me if my method is correct. I feel like the substation $b=e$ is a stretch and that there is a better way to do it.

---

We know that $G$ is Abelian $\iff (ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$. So I know that we will have to manipulate $aba = b$ into $(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$.

But this is where I get stuck.
$$aba = b \implies ab = ba^{-1} \implies (ab)^{-1} = (ba^{-1})^{-1} \implies (ab)^{-1}=ab^{-1}$$
This is close, but not what I want. One thing that I did notice is that if $b=e$, then $aba=b \implies a^2 = e \implies a=a^{-1}$. Since $a^{-1}$ is a unique element we know that $a=a^{-1}$ regardless of what $b$ is. So if we make that substitution into out previous equation we get
$$(ab)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}$$
Therefore $G$ is Abelian.

Comment: Notice that $ab=ba^{-1}$ and $aa=e$ for $b=a$ and just substitute the value of $a^{-1}$

Comment: The substitution $b=e$ is correct, since $aba=b$ holds for *every* $a$ and $b$ in $G$.

Comment: Why is setting $b = e$ a "stretch"?  It is a completely standard result that if $g^2 = e$ for all elements $g$ in a group that the group is abelian. Therefore it's really quite natural to set $b = e$ to get $a^2 = e$ for all $a$ in the group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct.

If $a^2=e$ for all $a\in G$, then for any $g,h\in G$,

$$\begin{align}
(gh)^2&=ghgh\\
&=e\\
&=ee\\
&=g^2h^2\\
&=gghh,
\end{align}$$

from which it follows that $gh=hg$. Hence $G$ is abelian.

Answer (score 1):

The hypothesis implies an exponent of two for the group.  But then it is abelian, since $ab=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba$, for any two elements of the group $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Choose

$a = b; \tag 1$

then

$aba = b \tag 2$

becomes

$a^3 = a, \tag 3$

which implies

$a^2 = e, \tag 4$

$e$ being the identity element of $G$; thus,

$a = a^{-1}, \tag 5$

whence (2) becomes

$aba^{-1} = b, \; \forall a, b \in G, \tag 6$

or

$ab = ba, \tag 7$

and we see that $G$ is abelian. $OE\Delta$.